# Is LinkedTransferQueue thread safe?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, thread-safety

Java doc for concurrent linked queue clearly states that it is unbounded thread safe queue. Whereas, javadoc for linked transfer queue only mentions unbounded nature of the queue and says nothing about thread safety

I am not referring to transfer method.

Producer calling add method and Consumer calling poll method.

Comment: The rule is: Does it say it's thread-safe? Yes: Then it's (meant to be) thread-safe. No: Then assume it isn't.

Comment: I believe this but need solid reference

Comment: Yes it is thread safe.

Comment: I am not referring to transfer method but add Vs poll method

Answer (score 1):

In short the answer is yes, class `j.u.c.LinkedTransferQueue` is thread safe. Since collection class is thread safe you can call any of its methods from any threads safely including `add` and `poll`.

The following words from javadoc should be considered as a proof of that:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a LinkedTransferQueue happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the LinkedTransferQueue in another thread.

Also `j.u.c.BlockingQueue` doesn't make lots of sense in a single-threaded environment. I mean you may use it, but there are more lightweight solutions like simple `j.u.Queue` interface. The main application area of `BlockingQueue` is producer-consumer applications where consumer is able to **block** waiting for the next element, which might come only from another thread because the current one is blocked . Since `j.u.c.TransferQueue` extends it then its implementations also supposed to be thread safe.

Comment: Memory consistency is different from thread safety. Need to know if it's safe to call add and poll in parallel and be assured that poll will not return stale information or some intermediate state. Regarding Blocking queue , add / offerr /put code for linkedBlockingQueue or ArrayBlockingQueue uses Lock objects to maintain consistency and avoid race condition. Code for add / offer in LinkedTransferQueue does not use this approach. Please check the code.

Comment: @AmrishPandey I agree that memory consistency and thread safety are different terms but I personally don't see any points of talking about the former without assuming the latter. May be I'm wrong. Regarding `LinkedTransferQueue` - did you look at implementation details described in documentation inside the class - "Overview of Dual Queues with Slack" ? At first glance I can say that this implementation relies on CAS and thread parking. The implementation is based on algorithm http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf but with some improvemenents.

Comment: I have seen that CAS code. My concern is If poll is called just before CAS statement then will I return an element which is not yet added , which could have been tail element in ideal case. I have not debugged it well.  I looked out for source or reference doc but didn't come across anything justifying or against thread safety of LinkedTransferQueue

Comment: @Amrish Pandey: almost no class of the `java.util.concurrent` package uses the term “thread safe”. What kind of thread safety that is not covered by guaranteeing a *happens-before* relationship do you have in mind? Your description of your “concern” is not understandable.

Comment: Happens-before , atomicity and synchronization are different things. Not productive discussion